# How to open a new window from action link in wall's posting

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I want to have a custom link when i post to my wall that opens up a new modal window. I have the link and it redirects to a new page but i want this as a popup window.

parameters.actions = new
                {
                    name = "TEST",
                   link = "www.google.com",
                };

thanks.

Comment: Been poking around looking for the same thing.  FB seems to want to keep the pageviews within their frame.  Capitalists.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like FB makes only untrusted links as target=_blank. I deducted that by analyzing the code for other app's links and my app's links.

I couldn't find any documentation and tampering with actions didn't render any success either.